# How to print an array of objects from meteors helper

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I want to display an array of object in HTML page, so I did this :

```
Template.home.helpers({
contents() {
var contentArray = [];
var content1 =
{
'contentName': 'test1',
'contentSize': 'test1',
'contentType': 'test1',
};
var content2 =
{
'contentName': 'test2',
'contentSize': 'test2',
'contentType': 'test2',
};
contentArray.push(content1);
contentArray.push(content2);
return contentArray;
}
});
```

How can I display the "contents" in the HTML page ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you worked through the meteor tutorial? This is covered in the second step, [here](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/templates).

For you, the following should suffice as a basic model:

```
<template name="home">

  {{#each thing in contents}}
    <ul>
      <li>Name: {{thing.contentName}}</li>
      <li>Size: {{thing.contentSize}}</li>
      <li>Type: {{thing.contentType}}</li>
    </ul>
  {{/each}}

</template>
```

If this doesn't make sense it would be best to work through the first few steps of the Blaze tutorial first.

You might also want to take a look at the blaze docs, specifically `#each ... in ...` - http://blazejs.org/guide/spacebars.html#Each-in